# Word: Mail Merge guidance needed

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, mail-merge

I have an Excel workbook with the following generic data:
[image]

Using MailMerge in Word,   I would like to accomplish the following layout. Note the the number of row will not be fixed at two - or any number for that matter - when created. The number of columns however will be fixed.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: I haven't used mail merge in awhile, but a quick look does allow you to create rules for next record. You may be able to have that to create groupings like you are showing.

Comment: Look into the Directory or Catalogue mail merge. See http://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/38721-microsoft-word-catalogue-directory-mailmerge-tutorial.html

Comment: Thanks for this. It looks promising.